# On arrival visa at Doha for Philippine citizen, currently holding UAE visa as Technical Adviser

Tags: visas-on-arrival, filipino-citizens, uae, doha

I'm a Philippine national holding UAE visa. My designation is "Technical Adviser". Will it be possible for me to get on arrival visa at Doha (Qatar) airport? Please advice its most urgent I need to travel today evening.

Comment: What UAE visa do you hold? Are you a UAE resident? And what is your reason for visiting Qatar?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes you can**, if you hold a resident visa in one of the [GCC countries](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCooperation_Council_for_the_Arab_States_of_the_Gulf&ei=fhXWVKvPNo7taICsgYAM&usg=AFQjCNE6_nxoiPELp2yRxdXJOFuVGHnJcQ&sig2=AxIVf7cjvW764tkTiHl0GA&bvm=bv.85464276,d.d2s) (in your case UAE), you will be able to visit all the other GCC countries (except Saudi) as long as you are (for Qatar):

> - Currently employed in one of the [201 authorized professions].
> - GCC residence permit valid for at least 6 months.
> - Original passport valid for at least six months.
> - Possess a return ticket to point of origin.

There are a bunch of different "technical" jobs in the list of authorized professions, [check the list](http://www.moi.gov.qa/site/english/departments/Airport/resources/2011/01/19_20379.pdf) and if your job is listed there along with the other requirements mentioned above then **you will be able to land at Doha and get a visa for one month for a fee of QR100 be paid through credit card**.

Comment: The list does not mention "Technical Adviser". The OP might have to do some convincing with the local authorities.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid **Philippine citizens are not eligible for Qatar visa-on-arrival**, unless they are currently residents of [one of the GCC countries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperation_Council_for_the_Arab_States_of_the_Gulf). Quoting from the [visa webpage of the Qatar E-government website](http://portal.www.gov.qa/wps/portal/topics/visas%2C%20passports%2C%20official%20documents/visas/!ut/p/a1/rZLNUtswFIVfxSy8q61ry4kNOzftkAKBTstPrE1GluVYbWQJWQnk7SuDPWwChRm00tVcHek79yCCloi0dCfW1ArV0k1fk-lqCsdxvsiSm18XXzP4cT6fTC5PYwyngO4QQUQzUaGCVjFlNUASJyXmlNMUA09pFDGeVtGE9Z2stdo2qGi2f5WSwnvgpcdUa3lrfRgOfbBKC9b5sBMd7b54mnadVsa6raprwQTdeJViW-lujV3up8V0Ba-sHNDbGGeIiFKGD0yGEOIoyeAYojROY4xx1GuLP_f3JHcA_WcfLVr6MB8Y7hzDbGSYjwzXA8PtM8PPF4arkeHbC8P31pq9t7odUfK2xNkaEcNrbrgJt8bNorFWn_jgQ6Ua2lBJKypMLxoyJX0YimC9FRV3pQ1sw4PhdLApEFKKtXka76F3GtU5tkP6z5N-0-ICFemrJs-m6PcHsnI5V5L3iuTTJM_-l2XnR2wWs4XzQ1PbBKKtFVq-J4RD18GgfH7UtZQZ3gek3OPNTmeAE1pm-8dJkR8d_QNYoTNJ/dl5/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/):

> #### Countries that have a visa on arrival arrangement with Qatar
>
> The United States, Britain, France, Italy, Germany, Canada, Australia, New Zealand, Japan, the Netherlands, Belgium, Luxembourg, Switzerland, Austria, Sweden, Norway, Denmark, Portugal, Ireland, Greece, Finland, Spain, Monaco, the Vatican, Iceland, Andorra, San Marino, Lichtenstein, Brunei, Singapore, Malaysia, Hong Kong, and South Korea.

To get a visa you must therefore apply in advance. See [the aforementioned page from the Qatar E-government](http://portal.www.gov.qa/wps/portal/topics/visas%2C%20passports%2C%20official%20documents/visas/!ut/p/a1/rZLNUtswFIVfxSy8q61ry4kNOzftkAKBTstPrE1GluVYbWQJWQnk7SuDPWwChRm00tVcHek79yCCloi0dCfW1ArV0k1fk-lqCsdxvsiSm18XXzP4cT6fTC5PYwyngO4QQUQzUaGCVjFlNUASJyXmlNMUA09pFDGeVtGE9Z2stdo2qGi2f5WSwnvgpcdUa3lrfRgOfbBKC9b5sBMd7b54mnadVsa6raprwQTdeJViW-lujV3up8V0Ba-sHNDbGGeIiFKGD0yGEOIoyeAYojROY4xx1GuLP_f3JHcA_WcfLVr6MB8Y7hzDbGSYjwzXA8PtM8PPF4arkeHbC8P31pq9t7odUfK2xNkaEcNrbrgJt8bNorFWn_jgQ6Ua2lBJKypMLxoyJX0YimC9FRV3pQ1sw4PhdLApEFKKtXka76F3GtU5tkP6z5N-0-ICFemrJs-m6PcHsnI5V5L3iuTTJM_-l2XnR2wWs4XzQ1PbBKKtFVq-J4RD18GgfH7UtZQZ3gek3OPNTmeAE1pm-8dJkR8d_QNYoTNJ/dl5/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/) for information on how to proceed.

Comment: Why the down votes people?